# Accessing a class from another project

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I wanted access the package structure and various classes in "project B" in my current project, "project A". I've read multiple other answers that state I need to add project B into project A's build path, however I did so and none of the classes were visible to me.

Once I added project B to project A's build path, I found a little red x on the icon for project A.

It seems I've misunderstood something from all the other answers, and being a bit new I reckon I've missed something obvious people generally know and have neglected to mention.
I already tried refreshing both projects, to no avail.

Comment: It seems that I have no clue what you are talking about since no code, no screenshot no nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with a setup Project B for example containing

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public Test(int y) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

Then Project A containing

```
package test2;

public class Hello {

    public Hello() {

    }

}
```

All you have to do is right click on the project A project folder and add the project B folder to its build path.

You can then access the class from project B in project A by importing it.

```
import test.Test;
```

This may give you an error (red x) on project A if project B has its own errors.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOd4R.png) is what it should look like when you add the project to the build path

Comment: Oh wow I feel stupid. I expected that there would be some visible change in the project A structure but there is no observable change so I thought it hadn't worked. Thanks.